# Make A List Item Clickable (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make each list-item on [my site](http://whattotaketocollege.com) clickable but I'm not sure what is the best way to do it. Please help me out.

So here is the relevant HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Backpack <a href="#" title="Buy on Amazon" target="_blank"><img src="img/basket.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Buy" class="buy" onClick="pageTracker._trackEvent('Amazon', 'School Supplies', 'Backpack');"/></a></li>
    <!-- More List Items -->
</ul>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
.content ul li {
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 15px;
}

.content li li {
    // This is for when there are sub-categories.
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #f8d9d0;
    margin: 3px -10px -3px -15px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 30px;
}

.buy {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

// The next ones all deal with the shopping cart icon that appears only on hovers.

.listblock ul li img { 
    visibility: hidden;
}

.listblock ul li:hover img { 
    visibility: visible;
}

.listblock ul li ul li img { 
    visibility: hidden !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.listblock ul li ul li:hover img { 
    visibility: visible !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

How can I make the whole list-item clickable and still have the shopping cart icon and Google Analytics Event tracking still work? Is there some jQuery magic I can use?

I've tried using display:block for the Amazon links, but that seems to mess up the image placement.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use this jQuery snippet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121748/how-to-make-the-html-link-activated-by-clicking-on-the-li/16847686#16847686

Answer (score 26):

I think you could use the following HTML and CSS combo instead:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Backback</a>
</li>
```

Then use CSS background for the basket visibility on hover:

```
.listblock ul li a {
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 10px;
    display: block;
}

.listblock ul li a:hover {
    background: transparent url('../img/basket.png') no-repeat 3px 170px;
}
```

Simples!

Comment: That looks like it will do the trick. Do you know if there's anyway to automate this in Dreamweaver or Coda? I have 150+ list-items. If you're not sure, don't worry about it though.

Comment: If you have that many items you should really be using some sever side generation like Ruby on Rails or Django.

Answer (score 21):

The li element supports an onclick event.

```
<ul>
<li onclick="location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486110/make-a-list-item-clickable-html-css';">Make A List Item Clickable</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: MDN discourages the use of event handlers in HTML (such as `onclick=`). This approach could lead less maintainable code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#event_handler_attributes

Answer (score 14):

The key is to give the **anchor links a display property of "block" and a width property of 100%**.

**Making list-items clickable (example):**

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: this helped me, thanks!

Comment: This won't work for `list-style-position: inside` since you'll have a line break after the bullet

Answer (score 9):

Here is a working solution - https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/YMJYqW (edit: dead link http://jsfiddle.net/STTaf/)

I used simple jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').css('cursor', 'pointer')

    .click(function() {
        window.location = $('a', this).attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect solution for me, thanks. The demo link seems down so I made this codepen : https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/YMJYqW

Answer (score 5):

HTML and CSS only.

```css
#leftsideMenu ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgray;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#leftsideMenu ul li a {
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#leftsideMenu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftsideMenu">
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Russia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Afganistan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Landon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Scotland</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ireland</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Very bad answer, I've improved it. I will remove the -1 if you correct your "answer".

Comment: I've already corrected it with the edit. You could correct it yourself and I undo my -1.

Answer (score 4):

Ditch the `<a href="...">`. Put the `onclick` (all lowercase) handler on the `<li>` tag itself.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting all content inside link?

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="..." ... >Backpack <img ... /></a></li>
```

Seems like the most natural thing to try.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it is a late response, but maybe is useful for somebody else.
You can put all your `<li>` element content into `<a>` tag and add the following css:

```
li a { 
    display: block; 
    /* and you can use padding for additional space if needs, as a clickable area / or other styling */ 
    padding: 5px 20px; 
}
```