# Enable list item to clickable area in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

**Description:**
Following code piece is used in Android/iPhone for Roundabout carousal. Each LI is `100px x 100px` in width and height. And link is top of the LI.

```
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="aa">
    <ul class="roundabout-holder"> 
         <li class="roundabout-moveable-item">
             <a href="<%= url_for :action => :graph %>"> <%= label_for:link %></a></li> 
         <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"> 
             <a href="<%= url_for :action => :graph %>"> <%= label_for:link %></a></li> 
         <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"> 
             <a href="<%= url_for :action => :graph %>"> <%= label_for:link %></a></li> 
         <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"> 
             <a href="<%= url_for :action => :graph %>"> <%= label_for:link %></a></li> 
         <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"> 
             <a href="<%= url_for :action => :graph %>"> <%= label_for:link %></a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.roundabout-holder {
    list-style: none;
    width: 75%;
    height: 10em;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.roundabout-moveable-item {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted #999;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Current behavior**:
In the items, Anchor only behave as link (jump to the given reference)

**Expected behavior:**
When user clicked on LI, it should jump to given reference.

**Relative resource from stackoverflow**

[How do I make the whole area of a list item in my navigation bar, clickable as a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074454/how-do-i-make-the-whole-area-of-a-list-item-in-my-navigation-bar-clickable-as-a)

[Make A List Item Clickable (HTML/CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486110/make-a-list-item-clickable-html-css)

eventhough solution come to near my issue. i need to find generic solution. Because I cant set padding for all at onece or one by one, because link label may change time to time.

Added and tested asfollows
`display:inline-block;` and `padding` then issue is sorted, but time to time padding should be change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way is to do this:

```
$('li.roundabout-moveable-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('a').click();
    return false;
});
```

It will make sure that clicking anywhere in the `<li>` yields the same result as clicking the contained `<a>`.

Comment: With the e.preventDefault(); its was able to do.

Comment: This yields max stack size hit... Infinite function calls.

Answer (score 1):

A. CSS Solution

```
li.roundabout-moveable-item a{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

B. Jquery Solution

```
$("li.roundabout-moveable-item").click(function(){
    $('a', $(this)).trigger('click');
});

$("li.roundabout-moveable-item a").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // To prevent li-click being trigged
});
```

Comment: given example is with some different JS framework, I'm apply this is for jQuery Mobile and css, so still i dont hv the luck.

Comment: Given example doesn't contain a single JS code. It's pure HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just use `display: block;` in the css to style the `<a>` tag to take up the entire `<li>`.

Comment: it just nothing but adding display:block. already i hv tried.