# Make an li element clickable (not a link)

Tags: javascript, html

There is a very similar question asked here [Make A List Item Clickable (HTML/CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486110/make-a-list-item-clickable-html-css) that I read for help but I couldn't get it to work. I have a link on my webpage that looks like this

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ...>
```

that when clicked shows a menu containing an unordered list.

```
<ul role="menu" ...>
   <li role="presentation" value="thing" onclick="myFunction()"...> <span>some</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Now what I want is for this li element be clickable and act as if it is a link with the cursor turning into a hand and change color on hover. Then when one of the li elements in the unordered list is clicked I want the function "myFunction" to to run.

Comment: How could you not get the linked question to work?

Comment: ^^ What Evan said. Without saying that, this is just a duplicate, and will be closed accordingly.

Comment: Note: What you've put in `type` is incorrect, `type` on `a` elements isn't (remotely) what `type` on `input` or `button` is. See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) for details.

Comment: why you not put a tag within <li> element, like <li><a onclick='' href=''>link</a></li>

Comment: heres a solution using jquery `$("UL li").on('click', function (e) {
                window.location = "http://google.com";
                e.preventDefault();
            });`

Comment: I honestly don't see how it is a duplicate when every answer in the supposed duplicate uses a link. Obviously I want to select, not route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code:

```css
li.link span {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li.link span:hover {
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul role="menu">
   <li role="presentation" class="link" value="thing" onclick="myFunction()"><span>Text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok I don't know what I did wrong the twentyeleven times I tried the onclick before on my elements, but now it worked.. So then yes, I suppose it is a duplicate question. Either way, thank you for your answer Inkbug :)