# onClick property not added using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone explain why the onclick propery doesn't show up or get injected?
I need a way to click on this data.

Got a little test app here showing the issue

Look below to where I add the onclick property to the

That property never gets injected, although the ID property does

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAgAShL4UzKAyNekPt92Y78Us684Fkhv4s",
    authDomain: "sample-e2b57.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://sample-e2b57.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "sample-e2b57",
    storageBucket: "sample-e2b57.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "304885560213"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<html>
<body>

<ul id="singleBus-ul"></ul>

</body>
</html>


<script>
const singleBus = document.getElementById('singleBus-ul');

var ref = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(25).on("child_added", function (snapshot) 
{
    console.log(snapshot.key);

    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = snapshot.child("height").val();
    li.onclick = "location.href = 
    'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486110/make-a-list-item-clickable-
    html-css';" // ******** THIS DOESN'T SHOW UP !! ********** //
    li.id = snapshot.key;
    singleBus.appendChild(li);

})
```

Comment: set it to a function? li.onclick = function(){return "hi"};

Comment: I set it to a function - location.href - does not change anything. So this works in plain HTML doc, but not using firebase. It's like Firebase doesn't insert that property.

Comment: you set it to a string, has nothing to do with firebase. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick you need to pass it a function or function ref

Comment: What confuses me is that this works in a plain html doc and its a string      <ul>
          <li onclick="location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486110/make-a-list-item-clickable-html-css';">Make A List Item Clickable</li>
      </ul>

Comment: you're not assigning the attribute in this instance, you are adding an event handler. ie x.setAttribute('onClick','boo'); would show up on html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function or function ref to `onclick`. Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers)

Foe Example:

```
li.onclick = ()=>{alert('hello')}
```

Comment: no problem, glad i could help out. just marked as answered when you get a chance.

Comment: Will do I'm going to implement it now, I might a little hand :)

Comment: let me know if anything else comes up