# Flex box rendering like a column when it should be a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am putting together what should be a simple nav bar and styling with flex box. For some reason, instead of displaying as a row (horizontal), it is showing as a column (vertical).

I can make the links go horizontal using float:left, but then they don't stretch evenly to fill the nav bar.

My understanding is that `flex-grow:1` [should make each item occupy an equal amount of space](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). But this is not happening.

---

There are four declarations that are not working as expected:

`flex-direction` *The links within the nav bar are in a column instead of a row*

`padding` *Although the nav bar's padding is set to zero, it still appears to have padding*

`text-align` *The text within each `<li>` is not getting horizontally centered*

`flex-grow` *The links are not spacing out evenly*

---

I'm not sure if they are all stemming from to one problem, or each separate problems.

Here is a simplified snippet:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Curse of the Nav Bar</title>
<style>
nav {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row; /* not working */
 background-color: #d2d6d6;
 padding: 0; /* not working */
}
nav a {
 display: flex;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 border: 2px solid #727171;
 color: #727171;
 background-color: #c4c4c4;
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 2px;
 text-align: center; /* not working */
 flex-grow: 1; /* not working */
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
 background-color: #aaa;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <a href="#"><li>Once</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Upon</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>A Time</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>There</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Was</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>A Problematic</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Nav Bar</li></a>
 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I've used flex box plenty of times before, but never seen it behave like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your code, here is the corrected one, You have given all the properties to Nav, while you need to assign these to UL,

1. There is no need to give flex-direction: row as this is the default property.
2. Padding is also working now, please check.

```css
nav ul {
 display: flex;
        text-decoration: none;
 flex-direction: row; /* not working */
 background-color: #d2d6d6;
 padding: 0; /* not working */
}
nav li {
 display: flex;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 border: 2px solid #727171;
 color: #727171;
 background-color: #c4c4c4;
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 2px;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-grow: 1;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
 background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Once</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Upon</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A Time</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">There</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Was</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A Problematic</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav Bar</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: and one more thing, Li need to be the direct child of UL not anchor.

Comment: Thank you. This was the most clearly explained answer and helped me understand the source of the main problem. You also addressed the padding and text centering issues, so I am accepting yours as the best answer. (Appreciation to all who contributed answers!)

Comment: I edited the snippet so that the `hover` styling and `text-decoration:none` are now correctly targeted also.

Comment: (For anyone wondering, that edit is presently awaiting review. Will delete this comment once it has been reviewed and is visible to all.)

Comment: Something I had to look up (and I will post here in case others find it useful), is how to make the `<li>` elements clickable, since wrapping them within `<a>` causes the layout to break. Just add an `onclick` event. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582588/2454914 This combined with styling the `hover` on the `<li>` (not the `<a>`) and adding `cursor:pointer` to the `<li>` makes it behave as if it were an anchor.

Answer (score 2):

1. use the `flex` to `ul` not `nav`(You have to set `flex` to the wrap DOM of you elements you want them to `flex`)
2. I think better to use `ul` and  immediately `li` not `a`(`ul li a`)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #d2d6d6;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid #727171;
  color: #727171;
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Once</a>
    </li>
           <li>
      <a href="#">Once</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Once</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Once</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Once</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving display: flex to nav ul as well.

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
}
```

Now the Items are appearing in a row instead of a column.
By default, `ul` is block element so the display will be block for `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

In `nav a {...}` replace `display: flex;` out of `display: inline-flex;`

Here's the effect:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Curse of the Nav Bar</title>
<style>
nav {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row; /* not working */
 background-color: #d2d6d6;
 padding: 0; /* not working */
}
nav a {
 display: inline-flex;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 border: 2px solid #727171;
 color: #727171;
 background-color: #c4c4c4;
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 2px;
 text-align: center; /* not working */
 flex-grow: 1; /* not working */
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
 background-color: #aaa;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <a href="#"><li>Once</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Upon</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>A Time</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>There</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Was</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>A Problematic</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Nav Bar</li></a>
 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You take a simple change the

```
nav {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row; /* not working */
   background-color: #d2d6d6;
   padding: 0; /* not working */
}
```

**To**

```
nav ul {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row; /* not working */
   background-color: #d2d6d6;
   padding: 0; /* not working */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Curse of the Nav Bar</title>
<style>
nav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row; /* not working */
 background-color: #d2d6d6;
 padding: 0; /* not working */
}
nav a {
 display: flex;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 border: 2px solid #727171;
 color: #727171;
 background-color: #c4c4c4;
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 2px;
 text-align: center; /* not working */
 flex-grow: 1; /* not working */
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
 background-color: #aaa;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <a href="#"><li>Once</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Upon</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>A Time</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>There</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Was</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>A Problematic</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Nav Bar</li></a>
 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```