# Clicable <li> with <a> inside it and HTML tags for contact information

Tags: html, css, tags

I want the entire li element to be clickable not just the phone, could it be possible?

Also, are the HTML tags being used correctly for a contact information?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li a {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<address>
      <ul>
        <li class="">
          <a href="12345"><img src="./img/phone.svg"  /><span>Phone</span>
            <p>+1 (234) 567-89-00</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="email@email"><img src="./img/email.svg" /><span>Email</span>
            <p>email@email</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="my streeet"><img src="./img/address.svg"/><span>Address</span>
            <p>street</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </address>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can either set your styles to

```
a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%
}
```

or

```
li {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the end the a tag after the img

```html
<address>
      <ul>
        <li class="">
          <a href="12345"><img src="./img/phone.svg"  /></a><span>Phone</span>
            <p>+1 (234) 567-89-00</p>
          
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="email@email"><img src="./img/email.svg" /></a><span>Email</span>
            <p>email@email</p>
          
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="my streeet"><img src="./img/address.svg"/></a><span>Address</span>
            <p>street</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </address>
```

Or you can delete the a tag.
The image works without it, but the img won't be clickable

Answer (score 0):

A `li` is by default not clickable. You can solve this issue by either using javascript or by adding `height: 100%;` and `display: block;` to your `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Just give `a` tag 100% width and height and it will occupy all the space of `li` and li will become clickable another way of doing this is that just remove `li` and and insert a tag directly.

```
ul {
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: center;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    
    li {
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block; 
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }


<address>
      <ul>
        <li class="">
          <a href="12345"><img src="./img/phone.svg"  /><span>Phone</span>
            <p>+1 (234) 567-89-00</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="email@email"><img src="./img/email.svg" /><span>Email</span>
            <p>email@email</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="my streeet"><img src="./img/address.svg"/><span>Address</span>
            <p>street</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </address>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li > a { display:block; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

this one should work

Answer (score -1):

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486110/make-a-list-item-clickable-html-css)

Here is the answer for those who don't want to look there

```
<li onclick="location.href = '';">Make A List Item Clickable</li>
```

The list element supports a onclick event.

for your case just remove the `<a>` element and replace it with a text-node or a `<p>`