# wrap anchor tag around li element

Tags: html, css

I am creating navigation menu. I want to use css so that anchor tag is wrapped around li element but anchor tags are inside li element.

Here is html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Uutiset</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Foorumi</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Kauppa</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Messut</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Asiakaspalvelu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nakoislehti</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nae meidat</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is my less css

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  li {
    padding: 2% 4%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The only legal element allowed inside a `<ul>` is an `<li>`. You cannot have an anchor wrapped around the `<li>`. This holds true in HTML5, where an anchor can wrap around other block level elements.

What you have in CSS is nearly there, just add:

```
a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

And your anchor shall fill the entire space of the `<li>`.

---

Update for 2022: wrapping your `li` tags with `anchors` is now totally acceptable.

Comment: I disagree, but I could be wrong. See my answer.

Comment: Adding anchor inside list item would result a11y 'nested-interactive' issue!?

Comment: @singularity I don't think it does. ol / ul aren't interactive controls. DeQue isn't flagging it as an issue for me. Can you provide a source?

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE:

You should not have anything besides <li> a a driect descendant of <ol> or <ul>. https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.7/list?application=AxeChrome
It is an accessibility issue.

Please disregard the following opinion:

Putting anchor tags, or any tags, around list-items is perfectly valid at the time of writing this in 2022. Though it may be considered unusual or bad practice.

From the specs: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

> Any element whose computed value of 'display' is 'list-item' has a list owner, which is determined as follows:

> If the element is not being rendered, return null; the element has no list owner.

> Let ancestor be the element's parent.

> If the element has an ol, ul, or menu ancestor, set ancestor to the closest such ancestor element.

The "owner" of the <li> tag is not determined by its direct parent, but by the closest ol, ul, or menu ancestor.

No problems should arise, accessibility or otherwise, from putting other tags around it. As long as it is inside a ol, ul or menu at some level, it will find its owner. It's the only way you would make the entire <li> container including the bullet or number clickable.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="example.com/1">This is fine.</a>
   </li>
  <a href="example.com/2">
    <li>This link is the entire container.</li>
  </a>
  <a href="example.com/3">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <li>This has four parents before the &lt;ol.&gt</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 4):

Dont use padding in `li` , use `line-height` for the anchor text instead. This will make it cover full height of `li` element .

Here, have a look at this [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/seSPs/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a li clickable, but what you can do is expanding the a-link to the size of the li as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1121754/1068495

Answer (score 1):

Try this, give the padding to anchor instead of li. It is not possible to keep  outside li. Do style your anchor instead of li. Let li act just like a wrapper.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  li {
    a {
        padding: 2% 4%;
        border: 1px solid green;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
  }
}
```