# How to add anchor tag to text inside a list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this list

```
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

I wanted to wrap all the Text inside the list with anchor tag for example something like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using jquery. The content is created dynamically so i dont have any control over the code to edit.

I used this code from some tutorial but no success.

```
$("ul li").wrap(function() {
   var link = $('<a/>');
   link.attr('href', '');
   link.text($(this).text());
   return link;
});
```

Comment: I am not a jQuery pro, i tried with this code $(this).wrap('<a href="..." />');

Comment: [`$("li").wrapInner("<a href=''></a>");`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)

Comment: So what was the problem with `.wrap` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086453/wrap-anchor-tag-around-li-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('ul li').contents().wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Simply Use `.wrap()` in jquery

```
$('ul li').contents().wrap('<a />');
```

if you want add href attribute in the anchor tag

```
$('ul li').contents().wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4gbvb6e8/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)

```js
$('ul li').wrapInner('<a href="#"/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      var li = $(this),
        text = li.text();

      // li.html('<a href="">' + text + '</a>');
      li.text('').append('<a href="">' + text + '</a>');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

`li.html('<a href="">' + text + '</a>');` would pretty much remove everything in each `li`, since I dont know if that doesnt matter or not it's safer to remove the text and append an `<a>` using `li.text('').append('<a href="">' + text + '</a>');`

Comment: Perhaps one would find it overly complicated for the desired output

Comment: that doesnt entitle to downvote. my answer is not incorrect. its not most elegent but perfectly fine

Comment: The downvote tooltip reads "This answer is not helpful". perhaps someone thinks that the over-complicated nature of this answer is somewhat unhelpful when there is a much simpler solution. Jus' sayin' :)

Comment: thanks for your thoughts but i think `$.each` is far from over-complicated :) you can do almost everything with a lot less of code, but 1-liners have the disadvantage of being ultimate and non-flexible.