# Change image background color on hover

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this example of how it should look:
[image: Hover over image to change colour]

Please help me how to change image background color on hover, this is my code, as you can see in example above, color should be transparent

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
  -o-filter: brightness(50%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(50%);
  width: 246px;
  height: 180px;    
}

a:hover img {    
  background: blue;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 7"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/bianca_capstick.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 8"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/coffe_keyboard.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 9"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/typing.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you want to be checking if this code doesn't work in which browsers? All browsers? Some browsers?

Comment: And `a:hover img { background: blue; }` is worthless as this is changing the background colour of an image element, whereas this will only show on transparent parts of `PNG` or `GIF` images. You probably want the blue background on top of the image element rather than underneath it, so remove the `img` text from this CSS rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the alpha channel and a negative z-index

- **First**, you need to select the right element: `li:hover .image`.
- **Secondly**, you need to use `rgba` colors to achieve **transparency**.

  ```
  li:hover .image{    
      background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  ```
- **Thirdly**, push the actual images to the back:

  ```
  img {
      position: relative;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  ```

### Working example:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
  -o-filter: brightness(50%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(50%);
  width: 246px;
  height: 180px;    
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:hover .image{    
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.image a{
    height: 180px;       
    display: block;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div class="image">
                  <a href="#" title="Blog 7"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/bianca_capstick.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="image">
                  <a href="#" title="Blog 8"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/coffe_keyboard.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="image">
                  <a href="#" title="Blog 9"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/typing.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `background` on `a` tag instead of `img`. Adjust `color` & `opacity` accordingly

```
a:hover {
     display:inline-block;    
     background: #4AFFFF;      
}
img:hover{
     opacity:0.5;
}
```

Instead of

```
a:hover img {    
  background: blue;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
  -o-filter: brightness(50%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(50%);
  width: 246px;
  height: 180px;    
}
a:hover {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#4AFFFF;  
}

img:hover{
  opacity:.5;
  }

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 7"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/bianca_capstick.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 8"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/coffe_keyboard.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 9"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/typing.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

To make it work on hovering over text use this code [`li` is parent of `text` and `image` both so it should work fine]

```
li:hover {    
    background: #4AFFFF;      
}
img:hover{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
  -o-filter: brightness(50%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(50%);
  width: 246px;
  height: 180px;    
}
li:hover {    
  background: #4AFFFF;  
}
img:hover{
  opacity:0.5;
  }

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 7"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/bianca_capstick.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 8"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/coffe_keyboard.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#" title="Blog 9"><img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/typing.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you try this now you will see `gap` below `images`. Its only viewable on `stackoverflow`. When you will directly run this in browser you wont see any it.

> I have checked with `Chrome, Firefox and Opear` there is not `gap` below `images`

If for some reason you do see it. you can easily adjust it with `margin/padding`

Comment: haha nice, I made a big structural changes to the code with my answser, and you add one line of extra CSS. Well done.

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I'm hovering over the text part though.

Comment: Updated answer.. add property on `li` tag

Comment: Is this what he wants? When I hover over the images I get a white overlay with a blue line on the bottom.

Comment: @AkashKumar What if he wants the text to be clickable, too?

Comment: He can simply move `a` tag outside `li`tag making `a` tag parent of `li` tag

Comment: @Akash Kumar This is strongly discouraged by the W3C. The only legal thing inside a `UL` is a `LI`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086453/wrap-anchor-tag-around-li-element).

Comment: Is there any reason why we shouldn't any other tags inside `ul` ?

Comment: Thanks Akash Kumar, this is ok, but with your solution I have gap below images, and can't adjust it with margin/padding

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the effect using two divs:

```
.a{
background-color:blue;width:100px; height:100px;}
.b{background-image:url("https://graph.facebook.com/1475846409390270/picture?type=large"); width:100px; height:100px;}
.b:hover{opacity:0.5;}


<a href="#"><div class="a"><div class="b"></div></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code and edited it and produced a workable result from reading this article after a few minutes on Google: 
https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/

The result is done thus:

- Place the image in the CSS rather than as an `<img>` element because as an element it will always be on top, or more fiddly layers will be required.
- A downside of this is that a new set of CSS rules (copy/paste) will be required for each image but will each have a custom image associated (for each of your button links)
- The HTML has been simplified and all CSS is associated directly with the anchor link, the image is anchor link CSS rather than a child element.
- The actual colour change effect is caused by making a pseudo-gradient in the image, gradient being from- and to- the same colour so being uniform.
- I could not make this work this way *without* using the pseudo-gradient effect, ie using straight `rgba()` values, on codepen.

My codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNoxoZ

**I strongly suspect there is a better way of doing this. But this appears to be what you are looking for.**
*A better way IS shown by adding an `opacity` value, as in Akash Kumar's answer.*

**My Code:**

```css
    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .anchorImage {
      filter: brightness(50%);
      -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
      -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
      -o-filter: brightness(50%);
      -ms-filter: brightness(50%);
      width: 246px;
      height: 180px;       
      display:block;
    }
    
    .image1 {
      background:url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/bianca_capstick.png');

    } 
    .image2 {
     background:url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/coffe_keyboard.png');

    }
    .image3 {
         background:url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/typing.png');
    }
    
    .image1:hover {   
      background: 
        /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ 
         linear-gradient(
          rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.45), 
          rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.45)
        ),
        /* bottom, image */
        url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/bianca_capstick.png');
    }
     .image2:hover {   
      background: 
        /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ 
         linear-gradient(
          rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.45), 
          rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.45)
        ),
        /* bottom, image */
        url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/coffe_keyboard.png');
    }
    .image3:hover {   
      background: 
        /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ 
         linear-gradient(
          rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.45), 
          rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.45)
        ),
        /* bottom, image */
        url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/hostel2hostel/img/typing.png');
    }   
    .text {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="image">
              <a class='anchorImage image1' href="#" title="Blog 7"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum one</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="image">
              <a href="#" title="Blog 8" class="anchorImage image2"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum two</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="image">
              <a href="#" title="Blog 9" class="anchorImage image3"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum three</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot change image background color with CSS (at least the basic CSS properties), it is the containers background color you can change and in HTML the image has a higher priority so the background color of the containing `div`, `ul`, `li` might change with your CSS rules but you will not be able to see it.

My opinion: I think the effect you want is an overlay on the image on hover. You can have an hidden div that will become visible with a slightly transparent property that will make it look like an overlay.

From the CSS styling, you might need some javascript

**Amazingly** you were so close to fixing it your way.
Here is the hack

```
img {
  filter: brightness(100%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(100%);
  -o-filter: brightness(100%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(100%);
  width: 246px;
  height: 180px;
}

a:hover img {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(50%);
  -o-filter: brightness(50%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

instead of your `a:hover img {background: blue;}`

**Note:** the hover only affects the img property so if you hover over the text you might not see any overlay effect (you could edit the CSS to make that work though.)

Answer (score -2):

Did you try

```
a:hover img {  
    background: blue;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Yes I am, but nothing was happened

Comment: Marijan, you're: **1.** setting a background-color to image. This about that. **2.** you're first setting the background to blue, **3.** than you're setting the background-color to transparent. So your suggestion is wrong, from multiple perspectives.