# How to change background-color of the image when hover with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change background-color of the image when hover with CSS What I can use? Which is the best practice.?

I am working on project VueJS add vutify I have one component that have three cards
grid system vutify.

When hover an image, I should to change background-color of the image.
Here is my code, I have picked up two images online just for example
but my image in project are black when hover we should to put a background-color as 
red.

Here is my code:
This what I have created about animation I don't understand very well, anyone can help with it.
I want to achive exatle this thing when hover on image:
[enter link description here][1]
I want  to achieve this when click hover image to take this background color as picture.[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Thanks in advance.

```css
.img {

      background: #FFB6C1;
      transition: background-color 2s ease-out 100ms
    }

    .img:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
  <template>
 <v-container fluid> 
     <v-row  justify="center">
         <v-col cols="12" md="8">

       
         <section class="section-cards-product ">
               <v-row>
                 <v-col cols="12" md="4" class="pb-12"> 
                         <v-card   color="#201E1C" >
                             <v-img    src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/cooking.png" class="img"
                                   ></v-img>
                      
                                  
                             <v-card-actions class=" section-title-bottom" >
                                <p class="white--text mt-6 mb-6 ml-5 ">
                                     Test test
                                </p>

                                   
                            </v-card-actions>                              
                      </v-card>
                 </v-col>
               </v-row>
         </section>
         </v-col>
     </v-row>    
 </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: images can't have a background-color.

Comment: tacoshy I want when hover an image to change color.

Comment: @tacoshy they can if they have transparency or padding

Comment: try to remove the `.` for your selector

Comment: Change the image's container background-color. Not the image itself.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986068/change-image-background-color-on-hover) is the solution you looking for ,Use the alpha channel and a negative z-index

Comment: I have attachment link of what I want to achieve above on description .

Comment: I will see thanks Nilesh Mishra

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change image background color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986068/change-image-background-color-on-hover)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS Property `filter` to do so. The following code will make the image black-n-white when you hover over it. You can make the behaviour as you want.

Here is the code:

```css
img:hover {
        filter: grayscale(1);
      }
```

```html
 <div>
      <div class="carousel-image carousel-image-fachada" id="mapaFachada">
        <img
          src="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.webp"
          width="450"
          height="auto"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nidhi thanks but problem is how to match  hover css when click in the code with vutify.

Comment: @Ana Do you want the transition on hover or on click? If later, then there must be an event listener on vue which I am not sure about.