# correct semantics for ul in ul

Tags: html

I am writing `ul` inside `ul` to make a accordion type of menu. But when I check my code below in html validator it gives me these errors

```
Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
```

How can I write semantically correct html for ul in this case?

Here is my html

```
<nav class="row">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Uutiset</a>
                </li>
                <ul class="inside">
                    <li><a href="">Fringilla Condimentum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Fringillau</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Curabitur</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Mollis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Ipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Fringillau</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Curabitur</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Mollis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="">Foorumi</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Kauppa</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Messut</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Asiakaspalvelu</a>
                </li>
                <ul class="inside">
                    <li><a href="">Tilaa lehti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Muutos tilaukseen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lähetä uutisvinkki</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Anna palautetta</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="">Nakoislehti</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nae meidat</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: The error message is not about semantics but purely about syntax.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You must wrap every inner `UL`s with an `LI`, i.e.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="">Uutiset</a>
    </li>
    <li> <----
        <ul class="inside">
            <li><a href="">Fringilla Condimentum</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> <----
 </ul>
```

Comment: At permitted content (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) it says: "zero or more <li> elements, eventually mixed with <ol> and <ul> elements."

Comment: @yeti: now [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul): "Permitted content: zero or more <li> elements, which in turn often contain nested <ol> or <ul> elements.", so this answer by the-alpha is the right one, in my opinion ;)

Comment: @Tilt I agree, the latest [W3C HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) now says: "Content model: Zero or more li and script-supporting elements."

Comment: this way an unwanted bullet appears before the inner <ul>

Comment: That's a matter of `style/css`, for example: `list-style-type: none;`.

Comment: I'm having a huge straggle on trying to make this kind of menu (semantic and valid html menu) to appear good and actually open up when clicked upon on a "mobile" viewport. I found that i need to add <input>s and <label>s for these inputs, in order for the inner menu to open when clicked upon (assuming i don't want to use JS). is there someone who found a way to keep the html clean, and somehow make it happen for different mobile viewports?. would appriciate advises. oh. I have no problem with JS as long as code is short as well. would appriciate advises / link to somewhere i can read. thanks.

Answer (score 19):

The children (direct descendants) of a `ul` element must all be `li` elements. This is a purely syntactic requirement.

The way to fix the error depends on semantics, however. If the inner lists correspond to subtopics of the topic of the preceding `li`, then you should wrap the inner list inside that `li`, e.g.

```
            <li>
                <a href="">Asiakaspalvelu</a>
                <ul class="inside">
                    <li><a href="">Tilaa lehti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Muutos tilaukseen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lähetä uutisvinkki</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Anna palautetta</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Technically, this means just moving one `</li>` tag forward. You may wish to change the nesting, though, to reflect the structure, but this is for HTML source readability only.

If, on the other hand, inner list is just items at a lower level in some sense, without being subordinate to a higher level item, you could wrap them inside a `<li>` that contains nothing more, e.g.

```
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="">Uutiset</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="inside">
                    <li><a href="">Fringilla Condimentum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </li>
        ...
```

Technically this means just wrapping `<li>` and `</li>` around the `<ul>` element.

However, this would normally indicate a design flaw. If you just want some items to be more nested, you should do that with styling rather than markup. And a list containing inner lists without relation to the items of the outer list is rather confusing.

Comment: This should be the right answer to the OP. The previous answer just explains the siuation without providing a real-world solution. That anwser will cause a extra node in the 2nd level which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

This took me a little while to understand because I wrapped my inner ul in its own li tag and not within the li tag that my inner ul was attached to. If you wrap your inner ul in its own li tag you'll get an additional unneeded bullet.

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li>item 3</li>
 <li>Item 4</li>
 <li>Item 5 has sub items:
      <ul>
          <li>Sub Item 1</li>
          <li>Sub Item 2</li>
      </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Item 6</li>
 <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the inner `ul` inside an `li` element.

Answer (score 3):

IN li can hold ul. Nexted li and uls are possible

```
<ul class="classname">
    <li>
        <a href="">TEST</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <ul class="classname">
            <li><a href="">1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
 </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul style="list-style-type:circle">
    <li>Cucumber Test Scripts (GroupId: Info.cukes) 
    </li>
    <ul style="list-style-type:square">
        <li>cucumber-junit</li>
        <li>cucumber-java</li>
        <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
            <li>Supports use of Annotations for cucumber step definitions.
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li>cucumber-java8</li>
        <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
            <li>Supports use of Lambda Expressions for cucumber step definitions.
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li>cucumber-picocotainer</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

This is the idea on nesting lists in lists. Happy coding :)