# Element hr and ul context validator problem

Tags: html, css

When I run a test from validator.w3.org I get an error in the line of code. "*Element **hr** not allowed as child of element **ul** in this context.*" This is causing it. Looks like there is no problem. But the validator does not accept this.

My code is here:

```
<ul class="dropdown-mega-sub-nav">
<li style="display:inline-flex;margin-bottom: -12px">
    <a href="https://app.example.com/" rel="nofollow">
        <img src="/img/lazy.png" data-src="/img/domain-0941.svg" class="lazyload" style="width:40px" alt="Example"></a>
        <a style="margin-left:7px;font-size: 15px;font-weight: 500;color: #000;margin-top: 4px;background-color: #fff" class="dropdown-item" href="https://app.example.com/" rel="nofollow">Example</a>
</li>
<hr style="border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb63;width:185px">
<li style="display:inline-flex;margin-top:-6px;margin-bottom:-12px">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/">
    <img src="/img/lazy.png" data-src="/img/ecomme-3500.svg" class="lazyload" style="width:40px" alt="Example 2"></a>
    <a style="margin-left:7px;font-size: 15px;font-weight: 500;color: #000;margin-top: 4px;background-color: #fff" class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.example.com/">Example 2</a>
</li>
<hr style="border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb63;width:185px">
<li style="display:inline-flex;margin-top:-6px">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="/img/lazy.png" data-src="/img/other_services-3051.svg" class="lazyload" style="width:40px" alt="Example 3"></a>
    <a style="margin-left:7px;font-size: 15px;font-weight: 500;color: #000;margin-top: 4px;background-color: #fff" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Example 3</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation Error: Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599801/validation-error-element-a-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-ul-in-this-context)

Comment: You can't add an hr tag inside a ul. but you can insert an [hr inside a li](https://caninclude.glitch.me/caninclude?child=hr&parent=li)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `<hr />` as a direct child of `<ul />`,

Use `<hr />` element inside the `<li />` element. This will solve your problem

Comment: I put the <hr /> element inside the <li /> element but it is broken.

Comment: put the `<hr />` element at the end of the content of `<li>` element

Comment: Yes I put it but <hr /> didn't show up.