# How to fix this error code: r: Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html

I have made a simple website for school. I still get 1 error. I am using this website to get the error. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea
Does anyone know how to fix this error? Here is the html

```
<nav class="header">
                                    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                                        <li class="flex-container">
                                            <a href="index.html">Homepage</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="flex-container">
                                            <a href="product.html">Products</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="flex-container">
                                            <a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="flex-container">
                                            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <a class="close-hamburger" href="#">
                                            <span class="icon">
                                        close
                                        </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </ul>
                                    <a class="hamburger-menu" href="#menu">
                                        <span class="icons">
                                    menu
                                    </span>
                                    </a>
                                </nav>
```

Comment: You can't have an anchor `<a>` as a child of a `<ul>`. I.e. your last "close" anchor needs to be within a `<li>`

Comment: Try to view this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22599801/18337391

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you can't have an `<a>` anchor tag as a child of a `ul` unordered list.

It is working on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/marcysutton/pen/ZYqjPj) though. So it could be an issue with your overall code. Mind sharing a bit more?

Comment: Yeah true it works fine. But for this school project i cant have any errors and this is the error. If I try to put everything in a <li> i get an new error code: Element li not allowed as child of element nav in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the span then.