# Bootstrap div within a dropdown ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a templating engine, so that I **have** to have a div(or some marker) inside of a Bootstrap 3 dropdown.

When I do this, the formatting goes out of whack:

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lje5wvqd/2/)

Here's my sample code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
         <h1> Dropdown Test</h1>

        <button data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a>test</a>

            </li>
            <li><a>test2</a>

            </li>
            <div>
                <li><a>test3</a>

                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I do not think this is the correct way to go about doing this, if it is completely necessary you could just add an id to the div and then give it some padding-left... You would have to check across browsers to see if that worked though. I only looked at it in Chrome

Comment: Gotcha, I never thought about just adding some left padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm going to expand on my comment as well as what belinus was saying. I still don't think this is the best way to do it, but may be a temporary solution at least. I would put it in a ul (instead of the div) as belinus was saying, however I don't think a ul can be a child of another ul without being stuck inside of another li ([see this post about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129037/correct-semantics-for-ul-in-ul)), so here's what I think it would look like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a>test</a></li>
    <li><a>test2</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul id="test">
            <li><a>test3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then you could just add some css to that ul. In your fiddle I just added 20px and it looked lined up to me:

```
#test {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Hopefully this helps a little bit.

Comment: This did it, along with adding a list-style-type: none; Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lje5wvqd/7/)

Bootstrap dropdown menus are specific when setting the CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    clear: both;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you deviate from the ul-li-a order, you'll need to include additional CSS rules.  This is why SASS/LESS are good; they make it easy to extend CSS rules to other elements/classes without too much extra markup; however, I won't demonstrate SASS or LESS at this time, just take a look at the CSS you could include in your page, below:

I'

```
/* notice the missing '>' before the 'a' */
.dropdown-menu > li a {
    clear: both;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
/*  change colors, remove underline and turn on pointer */
.dropdown-menu > li a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li a:focus {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Your HTML also wasn't valid and didn't adhere to the Bootstrap setup.  To update your markup, you'd need to include a `.container` and `.btn-group`.  Additionally, the `div` was at the same level as the `li`, which was not preferred/allowed.  Finally, I've added a dropdown arrow for UX styling.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h1>Dropdown Test</h1>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" 
                        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
                        data-toggle="dropdown" 
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        >Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a>test</a></li>
                    <li><a>test2</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <div><a>test3</a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's a caveat, the above is an example and may not be advised to use in production.  You are applying the CSS to all links nested in dropdown-menu li.  If you have several levels of nesting, that style will apply to all those links; for that reason, consider modifying the CSS selector, perhaps use a class on your anchor links.

Comment: This helped me a lot with the styling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3
     <ul>
       <li>Sub-Item 1</li>
       <li>Sub-Item 2</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just tried this with the jsfiddle. It doesn't work for dropdowns.

Comment: Then it is an issue with Bootstrap, because that is how you are to structure nested lists in HTML. Otherwise it will not validate. You can see the W3C's word on it here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `<div>` directly inside `<ul>`. This makes the HTML invalid and it produces erratic results in different browsers. So, you need to edit the template to render it inside a particular `<li>` and add stuff inside it.

Comment: How do I group off several li's then?