# Background color change on hover for ul in html

Tags: html, css

Whenever I hover mouse on that `ul` the `background color` must be changed for both list item `<i>` and `<a>` tags.

**CSS**

```
.mainlist {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.submenu {
    list-style: none;
    display: list-item;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 15px;
}

.submenu li {
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.submenu li i {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}

.submenu li a {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="float:left;margin-left:-250px;width:200px;background-color:dimgray;">
    <nav id="sidenav">
        <ul class="mainlist">
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

How can I do that? I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Use a hover attribute like  " .submenu li i:hover" http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp  That's just a quick answer.  If I had more time right now I would draft something up for you

Comment: You don't have enough markup to create the menu you'd like, so your question is a little unclear until that code is added.

Comment: Side note, your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` can't be a child of a `<ul>`

Comment: That's not working. Because the margin spaces are left uncovered. The entire ul background must be changed.

Answer (score 1):

To change `children's` appearance on hover do something like this:

```
.submenu:hover li {
    background:red;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Added a snippet to show the effect you want.

```css
.mainlist {
  list-style: none;
  display:block;
  background:#35414f;
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  padding:50px;
  margin:0;
}

.mainlist li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #808b97;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px 0;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-bottom:1px solid #3a4654;
}

.mainlist li:hover {
  background:#1eae9a;
  color:white;
}

.mainlist li:hover .submenu li a {
  color:white;
}

.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  display: list-item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.submenu li {
  display:block;
  color: #808b97;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
}

.submenu li i {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:inherit;
}

.submenu li a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <nav id="sidenav">
        <ul class="mainlist">
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>
              Lorem Ipsum
              <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to always wrap your submenu list into another li tag.

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
 <li>
  <ul class="submenu"></ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE 2:** CSS change +  added Icon font

Comment: That's not working. Because the margin spaces are left uncovered. The entire ul background must be changed.

Comment: The code doesn't help beacause it displays icon in line and the hyperlink in another line. I want both to be displayed in one line.

Comment: You can display them both in the same line by using `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` on the i element. See the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `pseudo class` `:hover`, like this

```
.submenu:hover li{
    background-color:green;
}
```

And for the text to change color too

```
.submenu:hover li > a{
   color:black;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4gffzfh/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `css` `:hover selector`

```
.submenu:hover li{
   background-color: black /* or any color you want */;
}
```

Also, is not correct to place a `ul` element as a child of another `ul` element

Check this:
[correct semantics for ul in ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129037/correct-semantics-for-ul-in-ul)