# Ignoring CSS nth-child for submenu li?

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, selector

I am trying to hide several menu items from my mobile menu using the nth-child selector in CSS.

Here is the source code HTML and CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/jf1r12wh/

The HTML is something like this:

```
<ul class="mobile">
<li>Item 1</l1>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<ul><li>Submenu item 1</li>
<li>Submenu item 2</li>
<li>Submenu item 3</li></ul></ul>
```

I want to use the nth-child (or similar) to hide Item 1 and 2 on the mobile menu, but I don't want it to hide Submenu item 1 and Submenu Item 2, which it's doing.

I'm using this:

```
    .mobile li:nth-child(1){
    display: none !important;
}

.mobile li:nth-child(2) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The problem is that it's applying this to the submenu as well. How can I make it not to do that, and only apply to the main menu items?

Comment: **Specificty** ...look it up!

Comment: ...also, your HTML is incorrect,

Comment: I realized that after I posted. That actually isn't the real code, I was trying to type a quick example and messed it up. Thank you though.

Comment: If you want answer that affects your *real* code, you have to provide that. Otherwise we're wasting our time.

Comment: I can do that, but it's a Wordpress theme and it's really, really long. I don't think it's helpful for anyone, but I'll update it. Thanks.

Comment: That's why we ask for **minimal** demos that actually **demonstrate** the problem.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is show that the rule should only apply to direct children via the use of `>`

Like this:

```
.mobile > li:nth-child(2) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

As Paulie_D mentioned in his comment, this is a part of specificity.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a working snippet:

```css
.mobile li:nth-child(1){
    color: red;
}

.mobile > li:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mobile">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Submenu item 1</li>
      <li>Submenu item 2</li>
      <li>Submenu item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For future reference, I would also like to point out that the correct semantic for a `ul` inside a `ul` is for the second `ul` to be inside it's own `li`

*["The children (direct descendants) of a `ul` element must all be `li` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12129070/6049581)*". I've made sure that my code snippet reflects this for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. It's still hiding the submenu items.

Comment: That's strange, by all means it should work. I've added a working snippet to my answer for you. Can you replicate the problem that you are having inside a snippet or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure. On the suggestion of the commenter above, here is the actual source code for this: https://jsfiddle.net/jf1r12wh/

Unfortunately the source code generated isn't the same as the back end... I'm not sure what else to do. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Your snippet is wrong. For .mobile li:nth-child(1) the > is missing. So now it also colors Submenu item 1 red.

Comment: @Gerard that was done on purpose to show the difference between having the > and not having it :)

Comment: Well, at least it's documented now :)

Comment: @cma2032 I'm not at a machine at the moment. Will have a look at your fiddle in a bit. Thanks for posting it!

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to explain this, but it looks like it's forcing the submenu to reload using the same selectors, or something? So it's causing the nth:child selector to restart from the submenu. I don't know how to even modify this. I would assume if it wasn't doing that, then your selector would work.

Comment: @cma2032 i've had a look at your fiddle, but there isn't a single element that has the class `mobile` even though your CSS calls for it?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I realized after I posted that. The mobile class is used, but for some reason on the view source, it changed the id and class of literally everything it spit out. Since this is built on Wordpress I'm not even sure how to put the code into a JFiddle (since it's spread over so many interlocking PHP and CSS files).

Comment: @cma2032 I'd love to help you further, but it's not quite possible for me find a resolution without a working example of what you are currently experiencing. That's exactly what Paulie_D was trying to explain in his comments on your question: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) any answer I give you would be purely guess work (and therefore most probably wrong) and is not conducive to the format of a Q&A site. If you can somehow replicate the problem, let me know and I will be happy to have a look :) Good luck!