# How to create nested HTML from nested array of objects using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to convert a JSON response to nested div elements and append them using jquery.
For example, my JSON response is something like this.

```
[
    {
        name: "List one",
        arr: [
            {key: "A1"},
            {key: "B1"},
            {key: "C1"},
            {key: "D1"}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "List two",
        arr: [
            {key: "A2"},
            {key: "B2"},
            {key: "C2"},
            {key: "D2"}
        ]
    },
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

and I need to build a div structure like this

```
<ul>
    <li>List one</li>
    <ul>
        <li>A1</li>
        <li>B1</li>
        <li>C1</li>
        <li>D1</li>
    </ul>
    <li>List two</li>
    <ul>
        <li>A2</li>
        <li>B2</li>
        <li>C2</li>
        <li>D2</li>
    </ul>
    .......
</ul>
```

Currently this is how I tried,

```
jsonObject.forEach((item)=>{
    var subCategories = item.arr.forEach((subCat)=>{
                            return `<li class="list-group-item">${subCat.key}</li>`
                        })

    $('#nested').append(
        `<li class="list-group-item">
            ${item.name}
            <ul>
                ${subCategories}
            </ul>


        </li>`
    );
});
```

This is somewhat similar to React method. But I am getting undefined for subCategories. How do I achieve something like this using jquery?

Comment: use `map` instead of `each` and `get` after the `map`.

Comment: oh!!! I got it working using `map` and then `join` the array. Thanks gurvinder

Answer (score 1):

I understood my mistake, Since `forEach` method doesn't return anything, `map` is the right one to use, to return an array. Then join the array, otherwise, there will be commas in your HTML.

```
jsonObject.forEach((item)=>{
    var subCategories = item.arr.map((subCat)=>{
                            return `<li class="list-group-item">${subCat.key}</li>`
                        }).join('')

    $('#nested').append(
        `<li class="list-group-item">
            ${item.name}
            <ul>
                ${subCategories}
            </ul>
        </li>`
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to construct your html as a string and use `html` to update the `div`

```js
$(function() {
   var jsonObject = [{name: "List one",arr: [{key: "A1"},{key: "B1"},{key: "C1"},{key: "D1"}]},{name: "List two",arr: [{key: "A2"},{key: "B2"},{key: "C2"},{key: "D2"}]}];
    

  var html = "<ul>";
  jsonObject.forEach((i) => {
    html += "<li>" + i.name + "</li>";
    html += "<li>";
    html += "<ul>";
    i.arr.forEach((s) => {
      html += "<li>" + s.key + "</li>";
    });
    html += "</ul>";
    html += "</li>";
  });
  html += "</ul>";


  $("#nested").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nested"></div>
```

Comment: As per the requirement the secondary ul is not inside li.

Comment: @SarathSRajendran **As per the standard**, The children (direct descendants) of a ul element must all be li elements.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129037/correct-semantics-for-ul-in-ul

Comment: @SarathSRajendran if you know that, im not sure what is the point of the comment. Are you trying to suggest that i should answer invalid HTML code?