# Get Data from JSON to Accordion using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, foreach, append, accordion

I want to retrieve data by color name.
Here is the data

```
[{
  "0":{
     "colorId":"MINT (07MTS)",
     "child":[{
           "0":{
              "nama_warna":"MINT (07MTS)",
              "sales_order":"21-000617",
              "price_quotation_id":"13126",
              "number_p":"623289",
              "greige_roll":"1",
              "packing_roll":"1",
              "npb_roll":"0",
              "greige_kg":"17.45000",
              "packing_kg":null,
              "npb_kg":null,
              "gp_loss":"0",
              "pn_loss":"-1",
              "gp_percent":null,
              "sent_ratio":null,
              "unsent_qty":null
           },
           "1":{
              "nama_warna":"MINT (07MTS)",
              "sales_order":"21-000617",
              "price_quotation_id":"13126",
              "number_p":"623288",
              "greige_roll":"15",
              "packing_roll":"15",
              "npb_roll":"0",
              "greige_kg":"371.90000",
              "packing_kg":null,
              "npb_kg":null,
              "gp_loss":"0",
              "pn_loss":"-15",
              "gp_percent":null,
              "sent_ratio":null,
              "unsent_qty":null
           }
        }
     ]
  },
  "1":{
     "colorId":"L.CORAL (50COL)",
     "child":[{
           "0":{
              "nama_warna":"L.CORAL (50COL)",
              "sales_order":"21-000617",
              "price_quotation_id":"13126",
              "number_p":"622753",
              "greige_roll":"15",
              "packing_roll":"15",
              "npb_roll":"15",
              "greige_kg":"365.55000",
              "packing_kg":"327.02000",
              "npb_kg":"327.02000",
              "gp_loss":"0",
              "pn_loss":"0",
              "gp_percent":"10.5000000000",
              "sent_ratio":"100.0000000000",
              "unsent_qty":"0.00000"
           }
        }
     ]
  } }]
```

and this is code my accordion. I put the json data into the result variable

```
result.forEach((item, i) => {
      var html = `<div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a class="accordion-toggle pull-left collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#`+i+`">
                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-110" data-icon-hide="fa-angle-down" data-icon-show="fa-angle-right"></i>
                        &nbsp;
                        `+item.colorId+`
                      </a>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="`+i+`">
                    <div>
                      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2">Greige</th>
                            <th rowspan="2">Kartu P</th>
                            <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center">PCS</th>
                            <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center">Weight</th>
                            <th colspan="5" style="text-align: center">Statistic</th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Greige</th>
                            <th>Packing</th>
                            <th>NPB</th>
                            <th>Greige</th>
                            <th>Packing</th>
                            <th>NPB</th>
                            <th>G-P Loss pcs</th>
                            <th>P-N Loss pcs</th>
                            <th>G-P Loss %</th>
                            <th>Sent Ratio</th>
                            <th>Unsent QTY</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                          <tbody id="body-so"></tbody>`;

      item.child.forEach(val => {
        $("#body-so").append(`
                        <tr>
                          <td>`+val.sales_order+`</td>
                          <td>`+val.number_p+`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.greige_roll === null ? 0 : val.greige_roll )+`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.packing_roll === null ? 0 : val.packing_roll )+`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.npb_roll === null ? 0 : val.npb_roll )+`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.greige_kg === null ? 0 : round(val.greige_kg, 2) )+`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.packing_kg === null ? 0 : round(val.packing_kg, 2) )+`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.npb_kg === null ? 0 : round(val.npb_kg, 2) ) +`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.gp_loss === null ? 0 : val.gp_loss )+`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.pn_loss === null ? 0 : val.pn_loss )+`</td>
                          <td>`+(val.gp_percent === null ? 0 : round(val.gp_percent, 2) )+` %</td>
                          <td>`+(val.sent_ratio === null ? 0 : round(val.sent_ratio, 2) )+` %</td>
                          <td>`+(val.unsent_qty === null ? 0 : round(val.unsent_qty, 2) )+`</td>
                        </tr>
                      `);
      });

      html += `</table>
              </div>
            </div></div>`;

      $("#accordion").append(html);
    });
```

the data comes out all in one color name but I want the data to append according to the color name. I have added foreach based on color name but nested forEach loop does not work. Thanks

Comment: I got the solution from this issue
[Nested HTML from Nested Array of Objects using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234719/how-to-create-nested-html-from-nested-array-of-objects-using-jquery?noredirect=1&lq=1) thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the data structure of 'result' you can find the problem very quickly.

The result of a traversal of 'result' is an object that contains all the data, not the 'Item' object you think of. Similarly, the traversal of 'child' has the same problem.

In addition, if you need to traverse an object, you need to use for-in traversal.

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbbpT.png)