# echo ul if condition is met

Tags: php, html

Im making a quiz system, and if a user is an admin `Add questions` should appear. However I cant seem to get the `<ul><li><a href="admin.php">Add questions</a></li></ul>` to echo out as a drop down menu.

```
<?php
$admin = 1;   
?>
<li><a href="quizOptions.php">Quiz</a></li>
<?php if($admin == 1){ //adds admin feature.
echo'<ul><li><a href="admin.php">Add questions</a></li></ul>';
} ?>
```

Comment: What's wrong? You're really not explaining that part well.

Comment: The code you posted seems to work fine. What's the issue?

Comment: Its not echoing out for me

Comment: I'm guessing the PHP code isn't being executed. View the page source and see if you see PHP code there.

Comment: no way, this works fine. please try phpinfo() and show us the result

Comment: https://3v4l.org/pRBul

Comment: did you check if your <ul> doesn't have a hidden class? try page source

Comment: I edited the OP, It should be a drop down menu, however the Add question option is not appearing when I hover over Quiz

Comment: does your file have a valid **.php** extension, or does it have a **.html** extension ?

Comment: yes its a .php extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't place a `<ul>` within `<ul>`

let's strip out the PHP for a moment...

```
<li><a href="quizOptions.php">Quiz</a></li>
<ul><li><a href="admin.php">Add questions</a></li></ul>
```

So you've got an open and closed `<li>` then an open and closed `<ul>`. It would be assumed you have an opening `<ul>` tag before the first `<li>` tag. Therefore you are creating a condition equal to

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<ul><li></li></ul>
</ul>
```

This is malformed.

You need to either remove the `<ul>` tags in the admin php...

```
<?php
$admin = 1;   
?>
<li><a href="quizOptions.php">Quiz</a></li>
<?php if($admin == 1){ //adds admin feature.
echo'<li><a href="admin.php">Add questions</a></li>';
} ?>
```

or add `<li>` tags....

```
<?php
$admin = 1;   
?>
<li><a href="quizOptions.php">Quiz</a></li>
<?php if($admin == 1){ //adds admin feature.
echo'<li><ul><li><a href="admin.php">Add questions</a></li></ul></li>';
} ?>
```

So that your HTML list is properly formatted.

See here: [correct semantics for ul in ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129037/correct-semantics-for-ul-in-ul)

This issue is entirely HTML-based and is not due to any php problems in your code.

If the goal is a CSS-based dropdown list menu item, you may need to merely move the first closing `</li>`:

```
<?php
$admin = 1;   
?>
<li><a href="quizOptions.php">Quiz</a>
<?php if($admin == 1){ //adds admin feature.
echo'<ul><li><a href="admin.php">Add questions</a></li></ul>';
} ?>
</li>
```

This leaves the admin unordered list *inside* that first list item.