# Create nested JSON object from HTML elements structure

Tags: jquery, html, json, object, nested

I am working on a workflow configuration screen, and have a below structure on HTML  level:

```
<ul class="wfSteps">
 <li>
  <ul>
     <li><input type="text" value="a"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sequential">
     <li><input type="text" class="stepName" value="seq of a"> 
     </li>
     <li>
        <ul class="parallel">
           <li><input type="text" class="stepName" value="par of a2"></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="parallel">
     <li><input type="text" class="stepName" value="par of a"></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to export the JSON object in below format:

```
{    "stepBracket": [
  {
    "combinationType": "Sequential",
    "stepList": [
      {
        "stepName": "<stepName>",
        "stepBracket": {
          "combinationType": "parallel",
          "stepList": [
            {
              "stepName": "<stepName>"
             }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "stepName": "<stepName>"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "combinationType": "parallel",
    "stepList": [
      {
        "stepName": "<stepName>"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

I tried the Jquery map method, but getting stuck in nesting level. Any suggestion how can i achieve the required Json object data.

```
function build($query) {
  return {
    stepBracket: $.map($query.find('ul'), function (item) { 
      var f = {
            stepName: "abc",
            sequential: [],
            parallel: []
         };
      return f;  
      })
  };
}

var result = build($(".wfSteps:first"));
```

Comment: So you're aware, your [HTML is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129037/correct-semantics-for-ul-in-ul), as `<ul>` cannot be directly nested in another `<ul>`... it needs to be within a `<li>`  (`<ul><li><ul></ul></li></ul>`)

Comment: I have modified the html code