# Can you turn the <li> number itself into a link?

Tags: hyperlink, html-lists

Is it possible to turn the `<li>` number itself into a link but not any of the text inside?

I do know of workarounds, such as creating my own while loop with an increment +1 and formatting it to be similar to a list; however, I was hoping to maintain the structure `<ol><li></li></ol>`. Thanks for any help!

For example...
[1.](http://google.com) List Item One
[2.](http://google.com) List Item Two

Answer (score 0):

You can try answers from this page [How to make the HTML link activated by clicking on the <li>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121748/how-to-make-the-html-link-activated-by-clicking-on-the-li) or this code

```
<li onclick="location.href='page.html';"  style="cursor:pointer;">...</li>
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I wasn't even on the right track. JavaScript never crossed my mind. I'll try that! :)